# FileInputStream can't read file in Android R

Tags: android

```
File file = new File(filePath);
InputStreamReader is = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), charsetName);
```

simple piece of code.
i checked the following:

```
file!=null
file.isFile()
file.exists()
file.canRead()
```

everything is true. The program have the permission and can actually read this existing file, but put it in a FileInputStream, it throws the following exception:

```
     java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/XNR/Setting.gson: open failed: EFAULT (Bad address)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:492)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:159)
        ...
     Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EFAULT (Bad address)
        at libcore.io.Linux.open(Native Method)
        at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.open(ForwardingOs.java:166)
        at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:254)
        at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.open(ForwardingOs.java:166)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$AndroidOs.open(ActivityThread.java:7372)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:478)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:159) 
        ...
```

it works well only on a api 23 emulator now. maybe the issue is cause by some new mechanics of newer version android api?

funny thing is, i developed and tested it on a android r emulator exclusively 2 months ago and everything is fine, after tested on several actuall devices, the project was deemed done and finished, it sat in my hard drive untouched for 2 months, i can even see the same .gson file generated by it. almost looks like it just went bad on it's own.

Comment: Already in Android Q that path was not accessable. Where have you been all that time?

Comment: `The program have the permission and can actually read this existing file,` ??? How did you read that file not using FileInputStream?

Comment: thanks for the comment. i checked around and used getFilesDir(), solved my problem. but as i stated, this program ran perfectly on the same android Q emulator 2 months ago, and haven't been altered since then, i can still find all the files it generated and managed to read in the emulator, so hopefully you can understand the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Using getFilesDir() or getExternalFilesDir(String) to access storage instead of using Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() solved the problem, android no longer supports that since q based on the comment above.

Comment: getFilesDir() ? What API is that?